# Select one row from each group in a large data.table based on a condition

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table where the key is repeated a number of times, and one to select just one row for each key, using the largest value of another column.

This example demonstrates the solution I have at the moment:

```
N = 10
k = 2
DT = data.table(X = rep(1:N, each = k), Y = rnorm(k*N))
     X           Y
 1:  1 -1.37925206
 2:  1 -0.53837461
 3:  2  0.26516340
 4:  2 -0.04643483
 5:  3  0.40331424
 6:  3  0.28667275
 7:  4 -0.30342327
 8:  4 -2.13143267
 9:  5  2.11178673
10:  5 -0.98047230
11:  6 -0.27230783
12:  6 -0.79540934
13:  7  1.54264549
14:  7  0.40079650
15:  8 -0.98474297
16:  8  0.73179201
17:  9 -0.34590491
18:  9 -0.55897393
19: 10  0.97523187
20: 10  1.16924293
> DT[, .SD[Y == max(Y)], by = X]
     X          Y
 1:  1 -0.5383746
 2:  2  0.2651634
 3:  3  0.4033142
 4:  4 -0.3034233
 5:  5  2.1117867
 6:  6 -0.2723078
 7:  7  1.5426455
 8:  8  0.7317920
 9:  9 -0.3459049
10: 10  1.1692429
```

The problem is that for larger data.tables this take a very long time:

```
N = 10000
k = 25
DT = data.table(X = rep(1:N, each = k), Y = rnorm(k*N))
system.time(DT[, .SD[Y == max(Y)], by = X])
   user  system elapsed 
   9.69    0.00    9.69
```

My actual table about 100 million rows...

Can anyone suggest a more efficient solution?

---

**Edit - importance of set key**

The solution proposed works well, but you must use setkey, or have the DT ordered for it to work:

See Example without "each" in rep:

```
N = 10
k = 2
DT = data.table(X = rep(1:N, k), Y = rnorm(k*N))
DT[DT[, Y == max(Y), by = X]$V1,]
     X           Y
 1:  1  1.26925708
 2:  4 -0.66625732
 3:  5  0.41498548
 4:  8  0.03531185
 5:  9  0.30608380
 6:  1  0.50308578
 7:  4  0.19848227
 8:  6  0.86458423
 9:  8  0.69825500
10: 10 -0.38160503
```

Comment: This is because `.SD[..]` calls `[.data.table` for each group. We are aware of this, will most likely be taken optimised in 1.9.8. There are solutions on SO which get around this (usually using `.I`) you can find by searching. I'll update this post once optimised.

Comment: @Arun The `cran` version is giving a different result/error compared to `devel` version for the `.SD` solution (tested by Khashaa and AnandaMahto).  I am using the devel version.

Comment: @akrun, corone, if you're on 1.9.4, do: `options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)` and things should work fine. It was a bug in the new feature that was fixed in 1.9.5.

Comment: @Corone, not sure if you are aware but your code would return multiple rows per unique X if max(Y) was duplicated for a given X.

Comment: @docendodiscimus yes, good point.  In my actual case the data won't have ties (or it is as unlikely as getting a tie in the example), but yes the "condition" needs to be uniquely satisfied per group I suppose.

Comment: You could possibly give this a try: `unique(setorder(DT, -Y), by = X)`. For your larger sample data, the system.time on my laptop was all 0 for that approach. And it will guarantee exactly one row per X to be returnd, also in case of ties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be faster compared to `.SD`

```
 system.time({setkey(DT, X)
    DT[DT[,Y==max(Y), by=X]$V1,]})
  # user  system elapsed 
  #0.016   0.000   0.016
```

Or

```
system.time(DT[DT[, .I[Y==max(Y)], by=X]$V1])
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.023   0.000   0.023
```

If there are only two columns,

```
system.time(DT[,list(Y=max(Y)), by=X])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.006   0.000   0.007
```

Compared to,

```
system.time(DT[, .SD[Y == max(Y)], by = X] )
#  user  system elapsed 
# 2.946   0.006   2.962
```

Based on comments from @Khashaa, @AnandaMahto, the CRAN version (`1.9.4`) gives a different result for the `.SD` method compared to devel version (`1.9.5`) (which I used).  You could get the same result for "CRAN" version (from @Arun's comments) by setting the `options`

```
 options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)
```

NOTE: In case of "ties", the solutions described here will return multiple rows for each group (as mentioned by @docendo discimus).  My solutions are based on the "code" posted by the OP.

If there are "ties", then you could use `unique` with `by` option (in case the number of columns are `>` 2)

```
 setkey(DT,X)
 unique(DT[DT[,Y==max(Y), by=X]$V1,], by=c("X", "Y"))
```

#### microbenchmarks

```
library(microbenchmark)
f1 <- function(){setkey(DT,X)[DT[, Y==max(Y), by=X]$V1,]}
f2 <- function(){DT[DT[, .I[Y==max(Y)], by=X]$V1]}
f3 <- function(){DT[, list(Y=max(Y)), by=X]}
f4 <- function(){DT[, .SD[Y==max(Y)], by=X]}
microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), f4(), unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
# expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
# f1()   2.794435   2.733706   3.024097   2.756398   2.832654   6.697893    20
# f2()   4.302534   4.291715   4.535051   4.271834   4.342437   8.114811    20
# f3()   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000    20
# f4() 533.119480 522.069189 504.739719 507.494095 493.641512 466.862691    20
# cld
#  a 
#  a 
#  a 
#  b
```

#### data

```
N = 10000
k = 25
set.seed(25)
DT = data.table(X = rep(1:N, each = k), Y = rnorm(k*N))
```

Comment: Can I ask why `DT[, .SD[Y == max(Y)], by = X]` returns 2010 observations, whereas `DT[,list(Y=max(Y)), by=X]` returns 10000 (as it should)?

Comment: @Khashaa I get `DT1 <- DT[, .SD[Y == max(Y)], by = X];dim(DT1)
#[1] 10000     2`.  I am using  `data.table_1.9.5`

Comment: One thing I just noticed - this relies on the `data.table` being keyed by X (which I had said it was, then realised it wasn't!).  Turns out adding the key takes very little time though, so this is still a good solution.

Comment: @Corone You could use `setkey`, which may improve the timings.  I think a `microbenchmark` would give more info.

Comment: What I meant was that if you don't `setkey` you get the wrong answer.  When you group by X that changes the order, if DT is not already keyed by X.

Comment: @Corone Not sure how it will change the results. `V1` gives the `TRUE/FALSE` logical vector based on the original order (in the first solution) and it is used for subsetting the `DT`.  In the second, `.I` gives the `row index` which was used for subsetting.

Comment: Strangely, the error persists when I tried on a different computer with `data.table_1.9.4`. DT1 has `X` values 1, 7, 16 ...etc

Comment: @Khashaa Can you try it on `devel` version?

Comment: And the error gone, with `devel` version:)

Comment: But I don't think we should rely on a devel version as a general resort. Are we clear on what defines the expected behavior?

Comment: @AnandaMahto  I am using the devel version.  Could you confirm if the error persists in the cran version?

Comment: Any insight on why CRAN version gives different result?

Comment: Yup. Same results as @Khashaa with the CRAN version.

Comment: @Khashaa Could you try `setkey(DT, X)[, .SD[Y == max(Y)], by = X]`

Comment: @akrun, Still 2010 observations....

Comment: @AnandaMahto  No idea why it is so.  Perhaps Arun will give some insights..

Comment: @akrun `V1` doesn't give `TRUE/FALSE` in the original order - it gives it in the order of the sorted key, because the by part has to sort it.  See example I added to question where key is not ordered.

Comment: @Corone Thanks for that.  Sorry, I didn't test it on a unordered dataset.

Comment: @Corone If you use `.I`, it won't be a problem.

Comment: Oddly I only get the reduced set error on unkeyed DT.  If I do setkey(DT) then I get 10000 results.  Although I'm getting a slightly random number of results, around 2020-2040.

Comment: I'm not a data.table expert, but wouldn't the first two solutions in your answer return multiple rows per group in case of ties?

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes, it would return that.  My solution was based on the OP's code and the `ties` issue was not discussed in the question..

Comment: Sure, no problem.. I just wondered about that because the title is asking for one row explicitly. I commented on the question

Comment: @docendodiscimus  I did edited as a "NOTE".  But, I think he wanted to get a faster solution for the same code he wrote.